# Mangeto 2.1.5 app/locale folder missing for language Files

Tags: magento-2.1, language, magento2.1.5

I am trying to create a custom translation of my Magento Store.

I have created two separate store views - Deutsch and English. Both reference to a separate store language in the backend.

I was able to translate the Deutsch Store with frontend-inline translation, but It doesn't allow me to change everything I need.
I have read in other posts, that one way is to directly write into the language files itself - they are located in app/locale, which sadly doesnt exist on my server.

Is there a way to implement it or create translations differently?

I am new to Magento - so I'd appreciate detailed answers if possible :)

Comment: Why do you not download any free translation module from https://marketplace.magento.com and see yourself how they are made?

Comment: I tried to install it like the documentation said with the web setup wizard but after that my whole store broke :)